# Finding even or odd in assembly language

Tags: assembly, wombat-1

How can I check if a number is even or odd in Wombat CPU simulator?

In C++ we can say 
`if(num%2==0) even else false`, 
but there is no modulus `%` instruction in Wombat, so how can I find even or odd?

Comment: Use bitwise `AND` (whatever instruction corresponds to it in wombat) to check the least significant bit.

Comment: @Jester Wombat doesn't have such an instruction.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_Sim) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that's a very ... *limited* ... CPU :-) Without an `and` instruction, you may find it necessary to do a `divide` (by two) of the value, then a `multiply` (by two) of that result.

Assuming that `divide` is an integer operation, the half-value will be rounded or truncated if the original value was odd so, for example, both `4` and `5` halve to `2` then doubling that gives `4`.

The result of that half-then-double operation will therefore be identical to the original value if that value was even, otherwise it will differ.

So you could then use a `subtract` followed by a `jmpn` to choose an even or odd code path.

In other words, something like this:

```
Start:   read                  // read to accumulator and store.
         store    Orig

         divide   Two          // round to even then subtract original.
         multiply Two
         subtract Orig

         jmpn     WasOdd       // Choose even/odd code path.

WasEven: ...
         jump     Done

WasOdd:  ...

Done:    stop

Orig:    .data 2 0             // For original data.
Two:     .data 2 2             // For halving/doubling.
```

Keep in mind this is untested, but it's *probably* a good place to start. I'm particularly unsure of the `.data` pseudo-op but, based on sample code, the intent is to provide a size (byte count) and initial value. If I've misunderstood how it works, you'll need to adjust for that.